# Links to json files

Tags: scala, laika

my directory structure is

`├── xxx
│   ├── 01.md
|   └── 02.md
├── auth
│   ├── j1.json
│   ├── j2.json
│   └── j3.json
└── default.template.html`

And I link jsons from markdowns like Auth. It makes sense as we use there files as test scenarios and in json files we have credentials and roles. But if I try to generate html it fails on `unresolved internal reference: ../auth/aspect_admin.json`. I tried to exclude the link checking but without any help. The best would be to leave it as a link in md file but somehow follow the link and include the json as code block in generated html. Is it possible?

Comment: What does this have to do with scala?

Comment: Laika is scala library https://github.com/planet42/Laika. Otherwise it would be hard to find

Comment: Gotcha, the tagged ```laika``` is something else tho. It is a Node.js framework. That causes a lot of confusion. I would suggest removing the ```laika``` tag and linking to the repo in the question if a tag for it isn't present. On the other hand, it looks like there is a common confusion on that tag. We might suggest a ```laika-scala``` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug and will be fixed in next version https://github.com/planet42/Laika/issues/148